# Why is there extra space being added whenever I execute PHP code that updates any text field in a MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, text, space

I am building a blog site and am having trouble with updating fields in my MYSQL database. Whenever I hit the update button on the form that uses PHP, it adds extra space before the text string in the MYSQL text field. Here is the PHP code:

```
   //UPDATE TEXT
   $updated_text = $_POST['text'.$the_post['ID'][$n]];
   if ($updated_text != "") {  
     $sql = "UPDATE posts SET TEXT = '".addslashes($updated_text)."' WHERE ID = '".$the_post['ID'][$n]."'";
     $text_result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you output the result of addslashes($updated_text) to the browser inside of <pre> tags. Then you'll see what you're actually adding.  Likely you need to trim leading spaces before you insert.

Comment: This probably isn't directly related to your issue, but don't use addslashes() for escaping db input.  Use mysql_escape_string(), at least.  Addslashes is bound to miss some things, and escape some things that don't actually need escaped.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you have this problem, but you could first try using [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) to remove white-characters at the beginning and end of your string :

```
$updated_text = trim($_POST['text'.$the_post['ID'][$n]]);
```

If this solves the problem, it's because you are receiving those whitespaces from the form -- else... Well, strange ^^

A couple of other notes :

- When escaping data to send it to your DB server, yOu should use the functions that are specific to your DB. Here, you are working with a MySQL database, and the `mysql_*` function, which means you should use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) instead of `addslashes`.
- You are escaping the data you're putting in the `TEXT` ; but, to avoid [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should protect the data use in the `where` clause too.

  - If your `ID` is a char/varchar in DB, it means using `mysql_real_escape_string` on `$the_post['ID'][$n]` too
  - If your `ID` is an integer in database :

    - the quotes arround the value are not necessary : quotes, in SQL, are the string-delimiter ; there is no need for any delimiter for integers
    - you should make sure you are sending an integer to the DB ; for instance, using `intval($the_post['ID'][$n])`
  - This will not change anything about your problem -- but taking care of security is always best ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps its an issue of the text-area tag of your html - for example if its indented or so..

Comment: +1; I´ve had surprises with IDE's auto-formatting my code and adding spaces between the opening and the closing tag...

Answer (score 0):

I found that the empty mySQL field was inserting " " into my html form value, so I used:

$variable = trim($variable,"&nbsp;");

to trim the unwanted space.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space or line break (in your code editor) in between  and  then remove them. I had the same issue earlier, but is now fixed.